# Replace multi line code using python

Tags: python

I am trying to replace some lines in HTML file using python.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python
import os,sys,string,filecmp,shutil,stat,pwd,datetime,time,copy,glob,re,getpass,commands
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(os.environ['ADM_TOOLS'],'llib'))
import tooldets,CSrcPrj,comnfuncs,COraConnect

patchHtmlName = 'patchmaintenance.html'
f = open (patchHtmlName, "rt")
g = open ('file3.txt', "rt")
h = open ('file4.txt', "rt")
contents = f.read()
contents1 = g.read()
contents2 = h.read()

#" ".join(contents1.split())
newJSCode = contents.replace(contents1, contents2)

fp2 = open(patchHtmlName, "w")
fp2.write(newJSCode)
fp2.close()
```

While the code for File3 is :

```
}

 function fnIsValidEmailId(str)

And the code for File4 is : 

                document.getElementById("beforePage").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("afterPage").style.display = "block";
}
 function fnIsValidEmailId(str)
```

I want to replace the code of file3 to file4.

If I am trying to replace the content of file3 to a single line instead of multi line, then the code works fine and replaces it.

While executing the script, it does not give any error but does not show the desired output.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import re
...
...
newJSCode = re.sub(r'.*%s'%contents1, contents2, contents, re.DOTALL)
```

This will replace contents1 with contents2 in contents. I'm not sure whether I undestood which one is to be replaced, but anyway if you want the opposite just change contents1 to contents2 an vice versa

Comment: I tried using the above code, but the same result.. No swapping is done

Comment: Have you checked whether the parts of the 2 files have differences that are not visible just by looking at the file? (e.g. tab characters in one file vs. multiple spaces in the other file)